# 'Bundle' is a type,

Tags: c#, android, bundle

Below is a snippet of code that has me baffled.

It is C# being built on Visual Studio 2015 Community with Xamarin for use on an Android platform.

```
public static void aMethod(string text) {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
}
```

`Bundle` in the second line gets an error:

> 'Bundle' is a type, which is not allowed in this context.

I am using Android `TextToSpeech` and in order to get an `UtteranceProgressListener.OnDone()` I must pass an utterance id in the `TTS.Speak()` parameter set using a `Bundle` or the `UtteranceProgressListener` will not be called.

Why am I getting this error and is there a workaround?

My guess it is something obvious but I don't see it.

Jim

Answer (score 0):

You should change this

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
```

to this:

```
var bundle = new Bundle();
```

The `params` is a C# keyword. Thus it cannot be used as a variable name. For further on this, please have a look 
[C# Keywords](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Answer (score 0):

`params` is a keyword, try using different variable name.

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
```

Comment: I knew it had to be something simple (or ignorance on my part). My thanks to all.  50 years of this, too many programming languages, too many new things.  Again, thank you.